# Which method is run when Home button pressed?

Tags: android, oncreate, onresume, android-homebutton

I have a Home replacement Activity from within which you can launch a number of apps. When you tap the Home button, you are returned to my Home replacement Activity.

As I understand, tapping the Home button creates an intent to launch the Home screen and then starts that intent (I might be wrong, please correct me if I am!). If this is the case, I'd expect the `onCreate()` method to be run whenever the Home screen is created. On the other hand, when you launch another activity, the Home screen invokes `onPause()`. So returning to it makes me assume `onResume()` is invoked.

If someone could just offer some enlightenment into this matter, the basic question is whether `onResume()` or `onCreate()` gets called when I tap the Home button, but additional details are welcome, I'm working on stuff that utilizes this heavily and want to know a lot about it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Yeah, when the Home is put in the background, my question is what is called when you tap Home and return to the Home screen

Comment: You may want to override `onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> tapping the Home button creates an intent to launch the Home screen and then starts that intent

Correct.

> If this is the case, I'd expect the onCreate() method to be run whenever the Home screen is created

Not necessarily. If it is already running, it would be called with `onNewIntent()`.

> If someone could just offer some enlightenment into this matter, the basic question is whether onResume() or onCreate() gets called when I tap the Home button

Any time any activity returns to the foreground from a user input standpoint, `onResume()` is called. Home screens should be no different in this regard.

`onCreate()` is called when the activity *is created*. Existing activities are not created, but are merely brought back to the foreground. If what triggered the activity to return to the foreground was a `startActivity()` call, the activity will be called with `onNewIntent()` and `onResume()` (and usually `onStart()`, for that matter).

Answer (score 10):

**When you install application first time following method call one by one in Activity**

1. onCreate()
2. onStart()
3. onResume()

**after that when you press Home Button then following method call**

1. onPause()
2. onStop()

**Note**: onDestroy() method not call after press **Home** Button.

following code for demo purpose. first run your code in Emulator or Device and after that click HOME Button to check result in your console.

```
package com.example.checkdataversion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "main";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "oncreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onstart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onresume");

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onpause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "onstop");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "ondestroy");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you just have to override onAttachedToWindow()

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

And then easily catch home button pressed

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {

       //do some stuff 

    }
});
```

Take from http://nisha113a5.blogspot.fr/

Hope this help.

Comment: Applications no longer receive the Home Key press. This is to prevent hijacking the Home key.